# Database does not respond Azure Microsoft

Tags: php, database, azure-sql-database

I've been programming this server / database in Microsoft Azure. And I've created this PHP to control everything. The main goal is to create a website where you are able to register and log in, for this I need a database and server which handles all these values. 
In my code hoewever, the database doesn't seem to be storing anything, everything does what's expected, expect for the connection between database and PHP document. Therefore I turned to you guys, heard u'd be the best haha! 
Just FYI, first post, be nice :)

Here's my PHP doc.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submits']))
{
if (empty($_POST['usernames']))
{
  $error = "Fill in all the boxes";   
}
    elseif (empty($_POST['passwords']))
    {
      $error = "Fill in all the boxes";     
    }
    elseif (empty($_POST['emails']))
    {
      $error = "Fill in all the boxes";     
    }
     elseif(strpos($_POST['emails'], "@") === false)
{
     $error = "Wrong syntax: example@.com";
}
else
{    
    $username=$_POST['usernames'];
    $password=$_POST['passwords'];
    $email=$_POST['emails'];  

    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => "MY_SERVER_EMAIL", "pwd" =>    "   MY_PASSWORD", "Database" => "MY_DATABASE", "LoginTimeout" => 30, "Encrypt" => 1);
    $serverName = "(MY_DATABASE";
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);       
    $sql = "SELECT username, email FROM dbo.Login";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }
    $usertrue=TRUE;
    if($usertrue===TRUE)
    {
         $error = "Account added";
      $hashedpassword = md5(md5(sha1(sha1(md5($password)))));
      $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Login (username, password, email) VALUES    ('$username', '$hashedpassword', '$email' )";

         $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query );

         if($conn->connect_error)
         {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
         }
         echo "Connected succesfully";
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  

sqlsrv_close($conn); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

The form is named POST and the inputs are named usernames, passwords, emails and submits.

Grateful for answers! 
Anton

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, I am assuming that you have replace the values with some place-holder.

Nevertheless, there might be some typo. There $ServerName has a "(". and I believe the Insert statement is not formatted correctly (i.e., all $username, $password, $email) is not getting evaluated because it is treated as string.

Also, why are you checking for connection error after executing the insert query. It should be checked first and re-connected if it is not connected before executing the insert query.